# Delete data between two parameters excluding the parameters in PERL

Tags: regex, perl, awk, scripting, gawk

I want to delete any data between the two parameters **) and ;** excluding the parameters for just the **first occurence**

**Currently its deleting including the parameters.**

cat input.txt

```
) delete; 
Test 
Test
)delete;
```

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q)\E.*?\Q;\E//' input.txt
```

Current output:

```
Test 
Test
)delete;
```

Expected Output:

```
) ; 
Test 
Test
)delete;
```

How to exclude the parameters ?
Any help ?

**Any new solutions in awk is also appreciated.**

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output have the word `delete` at the last removed? since you said exclude the first occurrence

Comment: Tip: `\)` is a lot clearer than `\Q)\E`. If it's still not clear enough, use `/x` and add whitespace to your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify what to use as a replacement:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q)\E.*?\Q;\E/);/'
```

`'s/\).*?;/);/'` might be more readable.

You can also use look-arounds:

```
's/(?<=\)).*?(?=;)//'
```

I.e. preceded by `)`, followed by `;`, but they don't belong to the matched substring.

Comment: `s/(?<=\)).*?(?=;)//` is improved by switching to `s/\)\K.*?(?=;)//`, and `s/\)\K[^\n;]*(?=;)//` is better yet because it avoids the non-greediness modifier used for a purpose other than optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`

```
$ cat infile
) delete; 
Test 
Test
)delete;

$ awk '!f{print f=gensub(/(\)).*(;)/,"\\1 \\2","a");next}1' infile
) ; 
Test 
Test
)delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete only the very first occurrence of string between ) and ; (by seeing your expected output)then following may help you in same.

```
awk '!n{n=sub(/^\).*\;/,") ;")} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
) ;
Test
Test
)delete;
```

**Explanation:** So checking here if variable named n's value is NULL, it will be null before a single substitution made for `).*;`. So once it passes that condition it uses sub keyword of awk to substitute everything from ) to ; with `);` and saves it's response which will be 1 now as 1 substitution has been made, so next time this condition(!n) will never be true, thus it will substitute very first occurrence of `).*;` only. 1 means it will print the lines for Input_file.

Comment: Could anyone please let me know the reason for down vote here?

Comment: Done that now, actually because of not using code tags it was not clear either space needed or not, so I didn't put it there, kindly let me know if you are ok to remove -ve now.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/. delete./,") ;")}1' file

) ; 
Test 
Test
)delete;
```